# MS Access Forms : How to dynamically change the select options in a combo box?

Tags: ms-access

My MS Access form has a two combo boxes, `c1` and `c2`.

I need the `select options` in `c2` to change dynamically . . . when i select an option in `c1`. How can I do this ?

Each value in `c1` matches multiple values in `c2`. So if I select `Mike` in `c1`, the `c2` should provide only those options that correspond to `Mike`. Right now `combo box c2` shows ALL options.

**How can I restrict the options in `c2` based on what was selected in `c1` ?**

Thanks !!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use the AfterUpdate event from C1 and update the rowSource for C2
something like:

```
Private Sub c1_AfterUpdate()
    Dim iVal As String
    iVal = Nz(Me.c1.value, "")


    Dim S As String
    S = "SELECT Field from myTable where Field like '" & iVal & "'"
    Me.c2.RowSource = S
    'Optionally me.C2.Requery
End Sub
```