# Query - ComboBox - criteria select - MS Access

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, database-design, combobox

I have the following data (examples):

```
tblModel
Mod_ID  Mod_Num  Mod_Desc
1       0001     Model01
2       0002     Model02

tblArticle
Art_ID  Art_Num  Art_Desc
1       001      Article X
2       002      Article Y
3       003      Article Z
4       004      Article K

tblOperation
Op_ID  Op_Num  Op_Desc
1      01      Gluing
2      02      Sewing
3      03      Stitching

tblMaterial
Mat_ID  Mat_Num  Mat_Desc
1       B001     Blue
2       R001     Red 
3       K001     Black
```

And the data structure is as follows:

```
tblModelArticle
MA_ID  Mod_ID  Art_ID  MA_Description
1      1       1       Model01 - Article X
2      1       2       Model01 - Article Y
3      2       3       Model02 - Article Z
4      2       4       Model02 - Article K

tblModelOperation
MO_ID  Mod_ID  Op_ID  MO_Description
1      1       1      Model01 - Op Gluing
2      1       2      Model01 - Op Sewing
3      1       3      Model01 - Op Stitching
4      2       1      Model02 - Op Gluing
5      2       3      Model02 - Op Stitching

tblArticleOperationMaterial
AOM_ID  MA_ID  MO_ID  Mat_ID  AOM_Description
1       1      3      1       Model01 - Article X - Operation Stitching - Material Blue
2       2      3      2       Model01 - Article Y - Operation Stitching - Material Red
3       3      5      2       Model02 - Article Z - Operation Stitching - Material Red
4       4      5      3       Model02 - Article K - Operation Stitching - Material Black
```

My question is: How do I make a ComboBox dropdown in tblArticleOperationMaterial limited? That is, once I for example select "MA_ID" to be 1, I want to be able to select only the 1, 2, 3 as MO_ID. For instance if "MA_ID" 2 value was input, the MO_ID dropbox combox box would offer only options of 4 and 5 to be selected as MO_ID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

its called cascading action. search for cascading combobox or
check this :[MS Access Forms : How to dynamically change the select options in a combo box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25747819/ms-access-forms-how-to-dynamically-change-the-select-options-in-a-combo-box/25748014#25748014)

or similar question:
[Get ID Filed from a Combobox in a Text Box where 1st column set to 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29693122/get-id-filed-from-a-combobox-in-a-text-box-where-1st-column-set-to-0/29694005#29694005)

Comment: You are officially my favourite person in the interweb as of now <3.